# Showing that $\int_{\Bbb R^n} \mathop{\rm div} u\,dx =0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ for each $i$. How to show that $\int_{\Bbb R^n} \mathop{\rm div} u\,dx =0$?

It might help to use Gauss theorem. But it is not a bounded domain with smooth boundary.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense as-written.

Comment: Are you sure about this result? It seems that it is not even true for $n=1$.

Comment: I hope you agree with the change I made to your title...

Comment: If we set $x^2\triangleq\langle x,x\rangle$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$, the following function is a $$ u(x)=e^{\frac{a}{b+x^2}}\quad a,b>0\:\forall x\in\Bbb R^n.$$ For it we have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\frac{2ax_i}{(b+x^2)^2}e^{\frac{a}{b+x^2}}\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$$ but obviously $u\notin L^1(\Bbb R^n)$.